# "Duplicate implicit target name": how to use a subtitle name more than once?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How do I use the same subsection title in multiple sections of sphinx/rst?

I didn't think this was an odd use case.  I just want to iterate through the same subsection titles for each section.

```
############
TITLE OF ALL
############

-------
CHAPTER
-------

SENARIO ONE
===========

Description
-----------

SENARIO TWO
===========

Description
-----------
```

Generates this error:

```
design_spec.rst:19: (INFO/1) Duplicate implicit target name: "description"
```

Surely I'm not expected to come up with unique subsection titles throughout the whole document.  What did I miss?

It's complaining about the **implicit** target name generated by the titles not being unique.  What can I do about that?

Comment: This is not an error, it's more like a (very mild) warning, since it says INFO.

Comment: The only problem with this is that the id attribute for the second and subsequent occurrences of non unique subsection titles will have values that can not be known beforehand. I.e. while the HTML for the first `Description` subsection is `<div class="section" id="description">...`, for the second one it is `<div class="section" id="id1">...`.

Comment: I know it’s an old post, but I ran into this problem the other day and the proposed answer didn’t work for me either, so I filed an issue on `rstcheck`: https://github.com/myint/rstcheck/issues/76

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the info if you define an explicit target name for the second (and third ...) section "Description" like this:

```
...

Description
-----------

SENARIO TWO
===========

.. _description2:

Description
-----------

...
```

This additionally gives you the benefit of having a known anchor if you want to jump there (like *mypage#description2*).

Don't miss the blank line between _description and the following section title.

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me. Or rather, it still issues an INFO message which, in turn, was breaking our tests.  I had to hassle internally to get the test tolerance raised to `rstcheck --warning`. <eyeroll>

Comment: The "info" level is actually intended for this case of a "potential problem".
It changes to an "error" message, if you add a hyperlink `description_` because then it is unclear which section the link should go to. Sorry for the hassle, but raising the rstcheck level is IMO the correct solution.